# Distance between 2 points

Tags: javascript, distance, haversine

I want to get the distance between two points using Map V3 library,
and I want to get the latitudes and longitudes from the user.

What might be the fault here?

```html
<div class="form">
          <form action="LatLng" method="post" id="LatLng" class="LatLng">
           <h2>Source</h2>
           <input type="text" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude" value="" class="txt">
            <input type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" value="" class="txt">  
             <h2>Destination</h2>                                  
             <input type="text" id="Dlatitude" placeholder="Latitude" value="" class="txt">
             <input type="text" id="Dlongitude" placeholder="Longitude" value="" class="txt"> 
               <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="txt2">

          </form>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

<script>
var srcLatitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
var srcLongitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
var destLatitude = document.getElementById('Dlatitude').value;
var destLongitude = document.getElementById('Dlongitude').value;
document.querySelector('form.LatLng').addEventListener('submit', function (e){
    var lat1 = parseFloat(srcLatitude);
    var lon1 = parseFloat(srcLongitude);
    var lat2 = parseFloat(destLatitude);
    var lon2 = parseFloat(destLongitude);

    var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1);
    var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon2);

    alert(calcDistance(p1, p2));

    //calculates distance between two points in km's
    function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
    return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(6);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it alerts as NaN"? What do you see on the screen when you run your code?

Comment: Also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have used the alert method of Js to popup a simple Message.

Comment: And what does that alert show? Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code, you are assigning values to variables, well before submit button is clicked.
Instead, you should move these assignments inside EventListener function.

```
var srcLatitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
var srcLongitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
var destLatitude = document.getElementById('Dlatitude').value;
var destLongitude = document.getElementById('Dlongitude').value;
```